# Is there a faster way to search through a big (!) project in VS2010?

Tags: search, visual-studio-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's a good alternative to Windows' “Search for Files and Folders”?](https://superuser.com/questions/135423/whats-a-good-alternative-to-windows-search-for-files-and-folders)

I was thinking about Google Desktop or something similar. Why does this take ages (!) -> 10 minutes while on the internet when having it indexed once it is found in seconds? Isn't there the possibility to index the project once and have it searched fast (!)?

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Agent Ransack](http://mythicsoft.com/page.aspx?type=agentransack&page=home).  Google Desktop would work too.  Or, as an alternative, you could install Cygwin and use `grep`.

Comment: Not going to downvote but this answer (grep) doesn't work for large projects.  By large I mean tens of thousands of files with millions of lines of code.  For that size project you have to index the source and indexing takes time.  Once indexed, search results are fast.  Of course you have to save the index - and update the index as files are added/deleted/changed.  It's a non-trivial problem for large code systems.